# Adding colour shading between the intersection of the x and y intercept and below the data line in Rstudio

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I want to add a colour to display the overage on the following graph. I only want the colour to be to the right and above the red x and y intercepts and below the black data points (the purple portions). Is there a way that I can acheive this?

[image: Herd Size Example]

```
dput(sows.df)
structure(list(month = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 
29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39), median_sows = c(38148, 
99184, 160220, 220546, 280458, 299922, 299861, 299888, 299881, 
299858, 299842, 299882, 297148, 281136, 265270, 249300, 233270, 
217276, 201288, 185286, 169624, 153648, 139750, 123520, 119690, 
118217, 117078, 117614, 116856, 130318, 119923,117974, 122934, 
120326, 117946, 122952, 120328, 117946, 120287)))
```

This is the code I am using to create the graph in ggplot:

```
## HERD SIZE ##
sowherd <- ggplot(data=mydata_reduced_sows, aes(x=month, y=median_sows))+
  (geom_line(linetype = "solid", color="black", linewidth=1))+
  scale_y_continuous(name="Herd Size", breaks=seq(110000, 300000, 50000), labels=seq(110000, 300000, 50000), limits=c(110000,300000))+ 
  scale_x_continuous(name="Month", breaks=seq(0, 40, 5), labels=seq(0, 40, 5), limits=c(1,39))+ 
  theme_classic()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(color = "black", angle = 45),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color = "black", angle = 0))+
  geom_hline(yintercept=118000, col="red", lwd=1.0, lty=1, alpha=0.6)+
  geom_vline(xintercept=12, col="red", lwd=1.0, lty=1, alpha=0.8)
sowherd
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: FWIW sows.df is not a data frame here